# SSRS Radar Graph

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I need to create a radar type graph like the one below using SSRS. This shows individual risks plotted in the category they belong to. The height or distance from the outside of the graph is from the risks score (a number).

Is it possible to do something like this in SSRS, so far I have only managed to plot how many risks are in a category (see second image) which is not sufficient.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

Answer (score 0):

I would look up doing a 'Polar' chart type embedded in your report.  More info here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd239337.aspx